# Get instance of singleton service in startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have the following situation:

*startup.cs*

```
services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationManager, ConfigurationManager>();
ConfigurationManager configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager();
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(configurationManager.DatabaseConnectionString));
```

So, in order to create my context I need the connection string which this `configurationManager` provides to me. However, I would still like to keep the `ConfigurationManager` as a service.

Is there a way to do this without explicitly instantiating the `configurationManager` or is it perhaps even fine to leave it like this?

Comment: Use `IConfiguration` which gets injected into the `Startup` methods in ASP.NET Core

Answer (score 4):

You can use the service provider to get instances of services:

Build the services provider -
`var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();`

Get specific service -

`provider.GetService<T>();`

Although a better option would be to use the IConfiguration .NET Core provides - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Using this method you can set IConfiguration to parse your config settings in the `Startup` method. From there you can then inject these settings into the required classes.

Comment: Is Service Location the best way though?

Comment: No I would always go the IConfiguration route, I made an assumption that was a no-go for this question so I appended it to my answer

Comment: However, this call (GetService or GetRequiredService) will cause class regeneration even if it was added with AddSingleton

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to access the `IServiceProvider` while building the context:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
{
    var configManager = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfigurationManager>();
    options.UseSqlServer(configManager.DatabaseConnectionString);
});
```

However, here your best options might be to read the `Iconfiguration` injected in `Startup.cs`:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        HostingEnvironment = env;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyContext"));
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can do sth similar to this. 
I am not familiar with what you do with your configuration manager to provide a precise answer.

Basically you can do a pre-config inside your Program.cs.

Build your configuration here. As you can see i am passing `IConfigurationBuilder`.

```
Program.cs

 public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(AddDbConfiguration)
        .UseStartup<Startup>();


private static void AddDbConfiguration(WebHostBuilderContext context, IConfigurationBuilder builder)
{
    var configuration = builder.Build(); // you could instantiate you Configuration manager here and append to the configuration.
    var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("Database");
    builder.AddDemoDbProvider(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
}
```

source: https://medium.com/@dneimke/custom-configuration-in-net-core-2-193ff6f02046

Comment: That's a different scenario: in the provided example, the goal is to load configuration stored in a database. The resulting database is not accessible to the ASP.NET Core application.

Comment: @Métoule you are correct. Of course he could easily modify the code to fit his solution. I am using the same code like the one in the source i refer to. This is the way i go for my configuration. I find it to be very flexible. Also he can instantiate in Program to build a better IConfiguration. Which is already in the DI of asp.net etc.